# Issue with using WinSendKeys to automate in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am using the program WinSendKeys (http://ath.dcmembers.com/wb/pages/software/winsendkeys.php) to try to automate the recording of video from a connected video camera.

Here is my setup:

I am using a Windows Vista computer with a camcorder connected by FireWire. I use the PMBTapeImporter.exe (aka. "Import from Tape") program from Sony PlayMemories to record video straight from the camcorder to the computer's hard drive. I need to record 1 minute of video every 30 minutes.

To automate this task I am using WinSendKeys and this batch file:

```
REM Go to directory with the WinSendKeys program
cd \Users\Seibel\Documents\WinSendKeys
REM Start the program
start WinSendKeys.exe
REM Open PMBTapeImporter.exe, then after a 20,000 msec pause tab 5 times
WinSendKeys -x "C:\Program Files\Sony\PlayMemories Home\TapeImporter\PMBTapeImporter.exe" -xd 20000 -w PMBTapeImporter.exe {TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}
REM Click the mouse 100 pixels down the "Import from Tape" window and 10 pixels inward (this is along the menu bar to bring this window to the front)
WinSendKeys -m "Import from Tape" #%,100,10
REM Click the space bar to select the highlighted "Import" button
WinSendKeys -w PMBTapeImporter.exe {SPACE}
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,5) DO (
    REM wait 10 seconds
    timeout 10 /nobreak
    WinSendKeys -m "Import from Tape" #%,100,10
    REM select the button again to stop recording
    WinSendKeys -w PMBTapeImporter.exe {SPACE}
    REM wait 20 seconds
    timeout 20 /nobreak
    WinSendKeys -m "Import from Tape" #%,100,10
    REM select the button to begin recording again
    WinSendKeys -w PMBTapeImporter.exe {SPACE}
)
```

For the moment I am just recording a 10 second video every 20 seconds until I troubleshoot my issue.

My issue is that first `WinSendKeys -w PMBTapeImporter.exe {SPACE}` command in the for loop never works and I cannot figure out why. The second `WinSendKeys -w PMBTapeImporter.exe {SPACE}` after the 20 second pause always works but never the first. What am I doing wrong?

Attached is a link to a video of the computer while this batch file runs.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6sktsljp7un3bw4/issue.tvs?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Escaping Percents](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html). The `%` character has a special meaning for command line parameters and `FOR` parameters. To treat a percent as a regular character in a batch file, double it: `%%`

```
WinSendKeys -m "Import from Tape" #%%,100,10
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, any idea why this did work for the 2nd identical line?

Comment: @CephBirk Too many unknown for me: first, what does `WinSendKeys  -m "Import from Tape" #,100,10` command do (as in a batch, the only `%` _disappears_ from a command line if not used in a special context). And second, what does the `PMBTapeImporter` do in that case?